# JUnit test - check type of exception

Tags: rx-java2

I use this RxJava chain.

```
public Single<Object> updateData(Object object){
 return Single.defer(() -> {
   try {
     return Single.just(mApiProvider.updateData(object));
   } catch(Exception e){
     return Single.error(e);
   }
 });

}
```

And I want to write unit test where mApiProvider.updateData() throw custom **RecordNotFoundException**.

```
@Test(expected = RecordNotFound.class)
public void updateData_recordNotFound(){
  mService.updateData(new Object).blockingGet()
}
```

But this case failed with error: **java.lang.Exception:Unexpected exception,
expected RecordNotFoundException.class but was java.lang.RuntimeException**.

With this annotation is everything ok: *@Test(expected = Throwable.class)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most blocking methods wrap the upstream's checked exception into `RuntimeException`. You have to manually deconstruct an exception thrown and check the `getCause()`:

```java
@Test
public void updateData_recordNotFound() {
    try {
        mService.updateData(new Object).blockingGet();
        Assert.fail("Should have thrown RecordNotFound");
    } catch (AssertionError ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (RuntimeException expected) {
        Assert.assertTrue(expected.getCause() instanceof RecordNotFound);
    }
}
```

Comment: And custom exception must extend RuntimeException?

Comment: It is usually nicer to have custom exceptions extend RuntimeException so that your clients don't have to declare try-catch everywhere they use your code.

Comment: And what do with NullPointerException?  Assert.assertTrue(expected instanceof NullPointerException); ?

Comment: Runtime exceptions are not wrapped, you have to do `catch(NullPointerException ex) { }` with nothing in the catch body.

Comment: I use this: catch (NullPointerException | RecordNotFound e){
        return Single.error(e);
      }
With:
 catch (RuntimeException expected) {
      Assert.assertTrue(expected instanceof NullPointerException);
    }